# optimize weight coefficient: $\text{arg} \min_{\beta}\|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \|_F + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I would like to optimize the follow objective function, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $V_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Actually, $\beta$ is the weight of each $V$, what is the algorithm to get the optimal $\beta$? Here the first term is Frobenius norm and second term is $2$-norm, I am not familiar with this kinds of objective function, can someone help me understand this objective function? what existing software (R or Matlab) can solve this? or need code by myself? Is this similar to ridge regression or lasso or others?

Thanks.

$$\text{arg} \min_{\beta}\left\|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \right\|_F + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$$

Comment: This is ridge regression. You can see this by rearranging $U$ and $V_i$'s as $mn \times 1$ vectors by stacking columns.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand this. Find the solver to solve ridge regression.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri  I find that for ridge regression, the first term should be **squared** Frobenius. But my optimization function is NOT squared, how to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, I missed that. I think they are still equivalent in the sense that the solution with $\| \|_{F}$ for a given $\lambda$ is the same as solution with $\| \|^2_{F}$ with another $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks @ArinChaudhuri. It seems that **squared** Frobenius norm is more common than not squared one in cost function. So the solution for an optimization problem depends on the user's choice, right. But I can select the **squared** Frobenius norm in the first term instead of NOT squared one. It should also be OK. Please give some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri  If having constrain s.t.:  $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta = 1$, then can I see it as ridge regression? It seems not, if such case, what is the way to optimize it. Thanks.

Comment: You can eliminate one of the parameters, say, $\beta_k = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \beta_{k-1}$ and rewrite the objective function in terms of $\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_{k-1}$, or you could use Lagrangian term in the objective function to handle this constraint.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri  Thanks for your help. I will learn that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change $U$ to $R^{mn \times 1}$, called $y$, and for each of $V_1,...,V_k$ also change to $R^{mn \times 1}$ and column bind to form a new matrix, say $X$.

then the queation is ridge regression problem and the solution for $beta$ is:

$$(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T y $$

thanks @Arin Chaudhuri.