# Are three optimization equations are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, machine-learning

I want to optimize the following equation in order to get the optimal $\beta$, where $U \in R^{m \times n}, V \in R^{m \times n},\beta \in R^{k}$.

Are three optimization equations are equal to obtain $\beta$?

First One:

It is **NOT** squared Frobenius norm in the 1st term.

$$\text{arg} \min_{\beta}\left\|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \right\|_F + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2 $$

Second One:

It is squared Frobenius norm in 1st term compared First One.

$$\text{arg} \min_{\beta}\left\|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \right\|_F^{2} + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$$

Third One:

There is a coefficient $\frac{1}{2 \sigma n}$ which is also constant in the 1st term compared to First One.

$$\text{arg} \min_{\beta} \frac{1}{2\sigma n} \|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \|_F + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$$

I want to know if these three optimization are equal to obtain the optimal $\beta$? That is to say: the optimal $\beta$ should be same for the above three objective functions?

I understand the Second One can be equal to standard form ridge regression optimization problem as suggested by [optimize weight coefficient: $\text{arg} \min_{\beta}\|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \|_F + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247139/optimize-weight-coefficient-textarg-min-beta-u-sum-i-1k-beta-i)

When optimizing, can I arbitrarily add or substract constant coefficients for 1st or 2nd terms, (like First one and Third one)?

Thanks.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. However by choosing a different value of the parameter $\lambda$ you can make the third equivalent to the second.

Comment: @Rahul  Thanks. Can you point me out what is an appropriate algorithm to optimize Third One?

Comment: @Rahul      Is $\text{arg} \min_{\beta} \frac{1}{2\sigma n} \|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \|_F^2 + \lambda\|\beta\|_2^2$ equivalent to $\text{arg} \min_{\beta} \|U- \sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_i V_i \|_F^2 + 2 \sigma n \lambda \|\beta \|_2^2$?

Comment: Yes, minimizing $af(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $f(x)$ as long as $a$ is constant.

Comment: @Rahul  Thanks. May I ask one more question: generally, **squared** Frobenius norm is more common than just Frobenius norm, right?